# Simple document switcher functionality?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing an application that will allow a user to drag/drop specific files onto the application window, parse those files, put the contents into a table (via a `QStandardItemModel`), and add each file's name (or alias) to a separate tree view (which acts as the document switcher).

I'll use NotePad++ as a simple example.

[image: Example]

When I click any of the new files in the leftmost "Doc Switcher," it shows the contents in the right pane. Imagine that right pane is a table. And for instance, imagine that the list on the left is a list of .csv files that were imported into the application.

What I want to do is, upon clicking each item in the list, I want the corresponding parsed .csv file to show up in the table pane on the right.

My table is just a `QTableView` that displays the contents of the .csv files in a `QStandardItemModel`. Everything works when it comes to implementing the table and parsing the files.

I also set up a `QTreeWidget` as the "document switcher." Now, I need to link the document switcher selection to the table so that each file's respective contents will be shown in the table view.

I can have the application populate the `tableView` with the model contents when the `QTreeView`'s top level item selection changes. That's no problem. The problem is with what I should be checking for when that selection changes and how.

I'm unsure of how to implement this. How do I store a bunch of `QStandardItemModel` objects and then link them to their names in the document switcher? Should I even be doing that? Do I have to create a new `QStandardItemModel` for each file that is imported? Should I create one `QStandardItemModel`, then somehow save it to be pulled back up later and re-use that same table model object for each file that is added? I'm just unsure how how this is *supposed* to work and feel like I am missing a fundamental part of all of this.

Comment: You don't need "bunch of QStandardItemModel objects". CSV files are not that hard to parse when you need to show the file. Check my https://notes.sciter.com/ where on click on list item ("document switcher") I am loading and parsing HTML file (which is more complex than just CSV) each time when I need to show it.

Comment: I can watch document switcher signal (selection changed) and create new model for the current data. Your table view in the right should show the data, when you set the model. When new file item selected, delete existing model and create new one with new data. Otherwise you can use a single model, but reset its data each time you switch the file.

Comment: Thank you @vahancho. I wound up using your second suggestion: using a single model and resetting and repopulating the data every time the `selectionChanged` signal is emitted in my file listing. If you add your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest two approaches to solve your problem:

- You can watch document switcher signal (selection changed) and create new model for the currently selected data. Your table view in the right should show the data, when you set the model. When new file item selected, delete existing model and create new one with new data,
- The same as first approach, but instead of recreating model for each data change you can use a single model, but reset its data each time you switch the file.